# Is a for loop that ends up not even running once just as fast as calling an if statement to check the size first?

Tags: java, c++, performance, logic

I am trying to optimize a chunk of code where speed is very important and wondered if checking  the `int` that holds the number of times a for loop is about to loop and not doing the for loop if it is equal to zero was any faster or slower than just letting the for loop execute 0 times.

I realize that any speed improvement would be tiny; it just started to become more of a curiosity. Also would this be different from Java to say C++ or C?

Example:

```
size=0;
for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)
{
}
```

or

```
size=0;
if (size!=0)
{ 
    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Of course, in the real code the size is often not zero, but when it is which would be faster if either?

Comment: I would say that the second form is slower due to additional checks and code size. IMHO.

Comment: I don't know about speed, but if there is a difference it will be minor if not negative, if check around the loop is a lot less elegant. That said iterators are even nicer.

Comment: Why don't you just set the time you start each test, and the time after it executes?  Then you'll know which one is faster.

Comment: assume i already initialized the int i so that is not an issue.

Comment: It seems you are curious enough to ask, but not curious enough to measure.

Comment: i thought somebody might know exactly how it is called and handled and could there for give a more insightful answer than a clock could.

Comment: just time those block of code

Comment: @RustyH: Nobody can say "exactly how it is called and handled" without knowing: your target platform; your compiler; the compiler options you are using; the machine you are running it on; etc.

Comment: For almost any question posted on SO asking "Is A faster than B" the correct thought process is:  1) Are you sure it matters, because if it does you probably have a larger problem with your algorithm. 2) If you still think it matters, write a test case to call the code in a loop with enough repetitions to be statistically significant, with all optimization on. 3) If there is a difference, look at generated ASM code to learn why.

Comment: it doesn't matter i already decided that but then i started to think of it more on a logical and meta kinda of level and thought it might be an interesting question that somebody with a deep knowledge of c++ or other might know how it was called and could state their advice on it. thank you Mark Taylor for at least having real advice.

Comment: thats the point. it does not enter the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Academically? Yes, since every time the size *isn't* 0, it will run 1 extra comparison.

Realistically? No. When you're talking comparisons like this, you're counting nanoseconds, *especially* after the JVM creates the machine language and it gets executed directly on the processor.

Now, which one should you use. Probably the first one. It doesn't save time, and it's shorter and cleaner. Even better, Java has a for-each loop construct that makes it so you don't have to have the index at all:

```
String[] strs = ... ;
for (String str : strs) {
    // Do something with str
}
```

For arrays, this compiles to an indexed for-loop. For `Collection` objects:

```
Collection<String> strs = ... ;
for (String str : strs) {
    // Do something with str
}
```

This one compiles to a for loop with an `Iterator` declaration.

These are the best option if you don't need the index itself, since it compiles to the same thing after compilation, it's clear, and it's the same for both arrays and collections.

Comment: Thank you ill take it before the downvotes kill what little rep i have.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it doesn't really make that much difference, but as there is one more check in the second one, it would take more time to run the second one compared to first one.

Comment: when the size is greater than 0.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but in my opinion regardless of the value of size you still perform that check. That's the reason that you perform that check to be honest.